# Bulk insert from Azure Blob Storage with other language

Tags: azure, bulkinsert, azure-blob-storage

I checked there is similar case and the solution is to save the csv file as UTF8.
I tried but is not working.

Original data: `인천 부평구 청천동 394`

Imported data: `Ω▓╜Ω╕░, φÅëφâ¥∞ï£, ∞ä£φâäδ⌐┤, ∞êÿ∞¢ö∞òö5Ω╕╕,16`

```
BULK INSERT [DBO].[data]  
FROM 'datawithdifferentlanguagge.csv' 
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'myAzureBlob',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
    ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    ,FIRSTROW = 2
);
```

I'm working on Azure SQL.

Where is my error?

Comment: Have you change the databse's collation?

Comment: Hi, I had solved my problem by adding CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'Char'. Thank you!

Comment: @lazziegal, can you please let me know the format of the DATA_SOURCE(the format of the myAzureBlob)? thank you.

Comment: @IvanYang
`CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL myCredential`
`WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=xxxxxxxx'; `//generate from Azure Blob SAS

`CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE myAzureBlob
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
       LOCATION = 'https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net',
       CREDENTIAL= myCredential);`

Comment: @lazziegal, thank you so much:), I'll take a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, and thanks for @lazziegal sharing.

Adding

```
CODEPAGE = '65001',
DATAFILETYPE = 'Char'
```

can solve this kind of issue.

```
BULK INSERT [DBO].[data]  
FROM 'datawithdifferentlanguagge.csv' 
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = 'myAzureBlob',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    CODEPAGE = '65001', 
    DATAFILETYPE = 'Char'
);
```